# Undefined function UDF in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have an UDF that I am calling inside Dataframe but I get undefined udf.

```
global ac
ac = sc.accumulator(0)

def incrementAC():
  ac.add(1)
  return str(ac.value)

df = sc.parallelize([('Java',90),('Scala',95),('Spark',92)]).toDF(["language","rank"])

df.withColumn("lang_and_rank", expr("concat(language,'blah')")).show()

+--------+----+-------------+
|language|rank|lang_and_rank|
+--------+----+-------------+
|    Java|  90|     Javablah|
|   Scala|  95|    Scalablah|
|   Spark|  92|    Sparkblah|
+--------+----+-------------+

myudf = udf(incrementAC,StringType())
df.withColumn("lang_and_rank", expr("concat(language,myudf())")).show()

.utils.AnalysisException: u'undefined function myudf;'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function to be used with `expr` has to be registered:

```
spark.udf.register("incrementAC", incrementAC)
```

Also `accumualtors` used from transformations are not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps!

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, expr, concat, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

ac = sc.accumulator(0)

def incrementAC():
  ac.add(1)
  return str(ac)

#sample data
df = sc.parallelize([('Java',90),('Scala',95),('Spark',92)]).toDF(["language","rank"])
```

**Approach 1:**

```
#solution using usual udf definition
myudf = udf(incrementAC, StringType())
df.withColumn("lang_and_rank", concat(col('language'), myudf())).show()
```

**Approach 2:**

```
#another solution if you want to use 'expr' (as rightly pointed out by @user9132725)
sqlContext.udf.register("myudf", incrementAC, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("lang_and_rank", expr("concat(language, myudf())"))
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+--------+----+-------------+
|language|rank|lang_and_rank|
+--------+----+-------------+
|    Java|  90|        Java1|
|   Scala|  95|       Scala1|
|   Spark|  92|       Spark2|
+--------+----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem after I renamed my Java file/function.  I restarted my Spark server and copied over the JAR files, but I got the undefined function UDF error when trying to run my currently running Jupyter Notebook with the new JAR files.

The solution was to restart my Jupyter Notebook.  I suspect some bit of the running Python environment didn't get refreshed with the new UDF registration.